# Uncaught Reference error: Toastify is not defined flutter web

Tags: firebase, dart, exception, flutter-web

I am new to flutter web. I have implemented firebase login functionality in my flutter web application. This functionality works correctly in local. But When i deploy the website on my own server, if i enter correct credentials, it works correctly on live, but whenever i enter wrong password, at that time it gives me exception,

Uncaught ReferenceError: Toastify is not defined

I have used fluttertoast library to dispaly toast messages, i m not sure what is causing the issue, is this error related to toast message or related to firebase. Please see attached screenshot of error[image]

Is this issue related to fluttertoast library or related to firebase? How to resolve this issue, do we need to do any configuration related to domain in firebase?

I am using following code to signin User

```
Future<void> _signInWithEmailPassword() async {

    UtilityHelper.showToast(message: "Login clicked");
    _formkey.currentState?.save();
    bool _isValid = _formkey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    if (_isValid) {
      setState(() {
        _loginType = LoginType.normal;
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
      final hasResponse = await authProvider.singInUser(loginReqModel);
      redirectToHome(hasResponse, authProvider);
    }
  }
```

late UserModel _user;
UserModel get user => _user;

bool get isChangePasswordButtonShown =>
_authRepo.isUserLoggedInUsingPasssword;

String errorMsg = '';

```
  Future<bool> singInUser(LoginReqModel reqModel) async {
    try {
      final response = await _authRepo.singInUser(reqModel);
      if (response != null) {
        _user = response;
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      }
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      errorMsg = UtilityHelper.getErrorMessage(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [fluttertoast documentation](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterToast#toast-with-no-context) mentions that web support uses Toastify-JS. I think that you need to [add Toastify CSS and JS](https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js#adding-toastifyjs-to-html-page-using-the-traditional-method) to your `web/index.html` file.

I added the CSS above the Flutter initialization:

```html
<!-- Toastify CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">

<!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
<script src="flutter.js" defer=""></script>
```

And the JS at the bottom of the HTML in my `index.html`:

```html
<!-- Toastify JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
```

And then the toasts work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to flutter toast library that i was using to display toast message, it did not worked with live domain.

So replacing that library with oktoast library solved the issue